# Come posso esprimere "pareces agobiado" ("you seem overwhelmed") in italiano?

Tags: translation, word-choice, adjectives, phrase-request

Oggi mio marito mi ha detto "Què et passa? Sembles agobiada" (catalano, che è la lingua che uso in famiglia). 
Me l'ha detto all'ora di pranzo, quando si è accorto che ero molto pensierosa, silenziosa e che forse non stavo facendo neanche quello che toccava fare (cioè, mangiare). E probabilmente avvertendo una certa espressione contrariata sul mio volto.

Tradotto in castigliano sarebbe "¿Qué te pasa? Pareces agobiada" e in italiano

> Cosa ti succede? Sembri _____?_____.

O forse sarebbe meglio esprimerlo in un modo completamente diverso, non lo so.

Infatti, "agobiado/a", usato qui come aggettivo, è il participio del verbo "agobiar". Ho cercato questo verbo sul [dizionario spagnolo-italiano Zanichelli](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_spagnolo/Spagnolo/A/agobiar.shtml) e ho trovato

> 1 spossare, affaticare 
>  
>   2 opprimere 
>   3 angosciare

Quindi, potrei tradurlo come "angosciata", ma non mi sembra una buona traduzione: questo aggettivo non ha le stesse sfumature di "agobiada". Se mio marito mi avesse detto "sembles angoixada", che è la traduzione di "sembri angosciata", si sarebbe preoccupato molto di più, anche se la mia risposta è stata "non mi accade nulla" (tradotto in catalano, ovviamente).

Adesso arriva la parte difficile della domanda, quella di spiegare cosa significa "agobiado". Quando qualcuno ti dice "pareces agobiado" in spagnolo, in realtà ti sta dicendo "sembra che ci sia qualcosa che ti «*agobia*»". Ho usato il verbo "agobiar" che, secondo il [*Diccionario de la lengua española*](https://dle.rae.es/agobiar#169H9KA) della Real Academia Española significa

> 1. Imporre a qualcuno attività o sforzi eccessivi, preoccupare seriamente, causare grandi sofferenze.
> 2. Deprimere, abbattere; far sentirsi perso d'animo, vinto (non sono sicura di essere riuscita a fare la migliore  traduzione del verbo spagnolo "rendir").

Quindi, si ti vede preoccupato/a per qualcosa, un po' abbattuto/a, vinto/a per qualche situazione, perso/a d'animo, soprappensiero, con la testa perduta in qualcosa che sembra preoccuparti, un po' assente, distratto/a, con mancanza di concentrazione nelle facende quotidiane.

Un'altro modo di spiegare il significato di *essere "agobiado"* sarebbe dire che significa *sentire una sensazione di "agobio"*.  In questa [tesi di dottorato](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11011206.pdf) (dottorato di ricerca in Scienza della Traduzione) si trova l'originale di un testo periodistico di Vargas Llosa e la traduzione fatta dalla autrice della tesi, in cui "el agobio" è tradotto come "l'affanno". L'accezione numero 3 della  [voce "affanno" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000204.jpg)

> Preoccupazione che dà ansia; agi­tazione dolorosa; condizione apprensiva, inquie­tudine profonda (come per cosa che  opprima l'animo);  esperienza  di  pena,  pensiero  tormen­toso, angoscia

mi sembra una buona definizione del significato di "agobio", in particolare la sensazione di qualcosa che opprime l'animo e di preoccupazione che dà ansia. Quindi, quando qualcuno  afferma "pareces agobiado/a" ti sta dicendo che sembri avere preoccupazioni che ti producono ansia, qualcosa che ti opprime l'animo.

Come posso esprimere questo in italiano?

Credo che una buona traduzione di "agobiado"
in inglese sia "overwhelmed". Ho cercato alle voci "overwhelm" del [dizionario Collins inglese-italiano](https://www.wordreference.com/enit/overwhelm) e del [dizionario Sansoni](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Inglese/O/overwhelm.shtml), ma quello che ho trovato non mi risulta convincente.

---

Un fatto curioso è che "agobiado" è una parola imparentata ("cognate") con "gibbo", "gobba", "gobbo" e "gibboso" e ha anche il senso, oggi in disuso, di aggettivo per descrivere qualcuno che ha la parte superiore del corpo inclinata o incurvata verso la terra, in particolare, a causa di un peso sulla schiena. Infatti, l'utilizzo di "agobiado" che ho descritto si può prendere come un uso figurato di questa accezione, ma è l'unico che è sopravvissuto nello spagnolo attuale.

---

Ecco alcuni esempi letterari di uso di "agobiado". Magari qualcuno riesce a trovarne le traduzioni in italiano (ho controllato che esistono). Il grassetto è mio in tutti i testi.

Da *La tregua* di Mario Benedetti.  Nella frase in cui appare il termine, il narratore spiega che durante quasi un anno si era sentito "agobiado" ("overwhelmed") da tre cose: il dolore, il lavoro e i figli:

> Pobre Isabel. Creía que, sacando el solitario, ya había convencido al destino, y únicamente lo había provocado. Todo está tan lejano, tan lejano. Hasta el marido de Isabel, el destinatario de esa carta de 1935 que era yo mismo, hasta ése también está ahora lejos, no sé si para bien o para mal. "No te rías", me dice y me repite. Y era cierto: yo me reía en ese entonces muy seguido y a ella mi risa le caía mal. No le gustaban las arrugas que se me formaban junto a los ojos cuando me reía, ni encontraba graciosa la causa de mi risa, ni podía evitar sentirse molesta y agresiva cuando yo me reía. Cuando estábamos con otra gente y yo me reía, ella me miraba con ojos de censura, que anticipaban el reproche posterior para cuando estábamos solos: "No te rías, por favor, quedas horrible". Cuando ella murió, la risa se me cayó de la boca. Anduve casi un año **agobiado** por tres cosas: el dolor, el trabajo y los hijos. Después volvió el equilibrio, volvió el aplomo, volvió la calma. Pero la risa no volvió.

Da *Una casa en la arena* (*Una casa nella sabbia*) di Pablo Neruda. Si tratta della parte finale della poesia *Amor para este libro* (*Amore per questo libro*). Tradotti letteralmente, i versi in cui appare il termine dicono: "e al *agobiado*, all'essere fratello, al ferito // abbiamo dato la libertà raccolta nel vento":

> Pedimos al océano su rosa, 
>   su estrella abierta, su contacto amargo 
>   y al **agobiado**, al ser hermano, al herido 
>   dimos la libertad recogida en el viento. 
>   Es tarde ya. Tal vez 
>   sólo fue un largo día color de miel y azul, 
>   tal vez sólo una noche, como el párpado 
>   de una grave mirada que abarcó 
>   la medida del mar que nos rodeaba, 
>   y en este territorio fundamos sólo un beso, 
>   sólo inasible amor que aquí se quedará 
>   vagando entre la espuma del mar y las raíces.

Comment: "Che ti succede? Sembri *sversa*". Oppure, con un anglicismo, "Stressata"?

Comment: "Angustiata" può essere una alternativa? È sinonimo di angosciata ma ha un peso minore di angosciata o tormentata. Forse ancora meglio "Afflitta"

Comment: Amareggiata, depressa, pressata, sotto pressione, oberata, sfiancata, oppressa?

Comment: "Agobiado" nella poesia di Neruda appare tradotto su [questo sito web](http://www.antoniogiannotti.it/--1966---una-casa-nella-sabbia.html) come "stanco": non mi sembra una buona traduzione, ma forse la poesia non è la migliore scelta per guardare questo tipo di cose.

Comment: "sembri affranta" / "sembri abbattuta" / "sembri sopraffatta" per me sono quelli che assomigliano di più al significato di "you seem overwhelmed".

Answer (score 1):

Ovviamente bisognerebbe sapere che espressione avevi e che cosa intendeva tuo marito. Comunque, alcune possibilità sono comprese fra quelle che dici, soprattutto “Sei preoccupata?”, ma per offrire qualche alternativa formulata in modo diverso:

> C'è qualcosa che non va / qualche problema?
>
> Sei (un po') giù (di morale)?
>
> T'è successo qualcosa?

Forse, vedendo queste, in una sorta di retroversione puoi cogliere se ce ne sia qualcuna adatta alla situazione che hai in mente.

Comment: Forse anche "abbattuto"?

Comment: Partendo da quello che ha scritto linuxfan, forse io potrei rispondere "ho l'anima sversa" come Melina nella *Malora* di Fenoglio (a chi non piaccia Fenoglio mi scusi il commento).

Comment: Personalmente non ho nessun problema con Fenoglio, anzi, ma sappi solo che “sverso” suona abbastanza esplicitamente connotato regionalmente (se non erro se n'era parlato in un'altra domanda). Come romano, non mi suonerebbe molto naturale.

Comment: Lo so, @DaG: era soltanto uno scherzo.

Comment: Mi è piaciuto il tuo prestito da Fenoglio, @Charo!

Comment: "Sei preoccupata?" o "C'è qualcosa che non va / qualche problema?" vanno benissimo, @DaG, grazie (anche se, come al solito, si perde qualche sfumatura).

Answer (score 1):

Un'altra parola poco comune che potrebbe fare al caso tuo è [crucciare](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/crucciare): *sembri crucciato*; *cosa ti cruccia*?